# Sending a floating point number from python to arduino

Tags: serial, python, float

I am trying to send a floating point number from a python script to an Arduino.  I am not sure how to do this, especially in a pythonic way.

A little bit of research brought me to this very similar question:
[How to send numbers to Arduino UNO via Python 3 and the module serial](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3753/how-to-send-numbers-to-arduino-uno-via-python-3-and-the-module-serial)
I vaguely understand why this would work for an int but don't know how to modify it.

1) In this question it makes sense to convert to a char, send, and then convert back to a int by casting on the Arduino, I can't think how to do that for a float.

2) Why do they convert to a Char anyway?

3) What code do I run on the arduino to get this back into a float?

4) Can I use bitwise operators on floating point numbers?

I'm new to python and also to low level programming. I am also aware that python and low level don't mix to well. I am using Linux but ideally I need a cross platform solution. Although I would prefer to get it working then worry about cross platform later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this question it makes sense to convert to a char, send, and then convert back to a int by casting on the Arduino, I can't think how to do that for a float.

Instead of using a format specifier of `B` for an unsigned byte, use `f` for a single-precision float. AVR-GCC doesn't support double-precision floats, so don't bother with `d`.

> Why do they convert to a Char anyway?

You don't. You convert it to bytes (hence the `b` prefix on the representation of the value) so that the byte-oriented serial protocol can transmit it. On Python 2.x `str` is already bytes, so no prefix is required there.

> What code do I run on the arduino to get this back into a float?

Use `Serial.readBytes()` to dump the bytes from the serial connection into a `float` variable.

```
float f;
 ...
if (Serial.readBytes((char*)&f, sizeof(f)) != sizeof(f)) {
   ...
```

> Can I use bitwise operators on floating point numbers?

... Well... no... because they may not necessarily remain valid floating point numbers afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer, this is exactly what I want, but this line doesn't work: I'm not really sure what I am doing wrong here, err msg: ser.write(struct.pack(@f,volt_out))
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: The format must be specified as a string. `struct.pack('...', ...)`

Comment: Thanks, it works :) I changed the arduino side code `while(!Serial.available()); float f; Serial.readBytes((char*)&f, sizeof(f));` the if statement seemed a little redundant in my setup

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers are (should) be stored in [IEEE 754 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

If you simply write the binary bytes of a floating point number down the serial line, it should be possible to unpack them at the other end.

To do this (Arduino C/C++), make a pointer from your variable, by casting the address of it to char*. Void* would probably work too.

```
 float my_value = 22.812;
 my_port.write((const char *)&my_value, sizeof(float)/*4*/);
```

And the unpacking - there's a few ways to do this, but I like:

```
 float incoming_value;
 unsigned char buffer[4];

 // If we read enough bytes, unpacked it
 if (my_serial.readBytes(buffer, sizeof(float)) == sizeof(float))
     memcpy(&incoming_value, buffer, sizeof(float));
 else
     // I/O error - no data, not enough bytes, etc.
     incoming_value = 0
```

On the other end (python), bytes are best handled with the **struct** module.  This will handle the packing and unpacking for you.

```
import struct
...

try:
    ieee754_data = my_serial.read(4)
    my_float = struct.unpack('f', ieee754_data)
catch:
    # I/O Error, or junk data
    my_float = 0.0
```

And packing:

```
 ieee754_data = struct.pack('f', my_float)
 try:
     my_serial.write(ieee754_data)
 catch:
     pass #TODO - I/O Error
```

One more note - You might consider using doubles instead of floats for extra precision.  Python floats have the precision of a C/C++ double already.