# How to send float numbers from python3 with struct to arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, float

I have searched several questions and through google but could not find a solution. I am simply trying to send a float number from python3 with struct to arduino or if there is any other ways other than processing a char array at the arduino side because it is very slow in my opinion..

My arduino code:

```
void setup() {
  // initialize the serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  unsigned long t = millis();
  float x = analogRead(A3);
  float y = analogRead(A2);
  float c = Serial.read();
  Serial.println(c);
  //Serial.print(t/1000.0);
  //Serial.print(" , ");
  //Serial.print(x);
  //Serial.print(" , ");
  //Serial.println(y);



  // wait a bit for the analog-to-digital converter to stabilize after the last
  // reading:
  //delayMicroseconds(200);
  //delay(2);
  delay(250);
}
```

My python3 code :

```
import serial

import struct

arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
data = arduino.write(struct.pack('f', 111.32))
while True:
#    arduino.write(b"123")
    data = arduino.write(struct.pack('f', 111.32))
```

Getting the serial output as :

```
163.00
222.00
66.00
215.00
163.00
222.00
66.00
215.00
163.00
222.00
66.00
215.00
163.00
```

How can i solve my problem ?

EDIT : I changed the arduino code according to the answer the new arduino code is

```
float f;
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  while(Serial.available() >= 3){

    f = Serial.read() << 24;
    f = ((unsigned long) f) | (Serial.read() << 16);
    f = ((unsigned long) f) | (Serial.read() << 8);
    f = ((unsigned long) f) | Serial.read();
    Serial.println(f);
  }
  Serial.println(f);
}
```

However, the output is now as such:

```
ovf
ovf
ovf
ovf
ovf
ovf
ovf
4294941184.00
4294941184.00
4294941184.00
4294941184.00
4294941184.00
4294941184.00
4294941184.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way dealing with the conversion from char to float (note that you yourself have to add the `setup()` function for initiating Serial):

```
float f;
byte *fdata = (byte *) &f;
int num = 0;

void loop()
{
  if(Serial.available()){
    char c = Serial.read();
    if(c == 'B'){
      fdata[3] = c;
      num = 1;
    } else if(num == 1){
      fdata[2] = c;
      num++;
    } else if(num == 2){
      fdata[1] = c;
      num++;
    } else if(num == 3){
      fdata[0] = c;
      num = 0;
      Serial.write(fdata, 4);
      Serial.println(f);
    }
  }
}
```

First we are defining our float variable `f` and then a pointer of type `byte` named `fdata`. We are setting this pointer to point to our float variable. Now you can treat this pointer as an array. Since the type of the pointer is `byte`, we can access the first byte of `f` with typing `fdata[0]`. The other bytes can be accessed through `fdata[1]`, `fdata[2]` and `fdata[3]`.

In the loop example we are checking, if there is any byte in the buffer and read it. If it is the value of the character 'B' (which I used as a trigger, that your float starts, since the float number `111.32` starts with this value) we copy it to the last (most significant) byte of the array (aka float variable `f`). One after another we are doing the same with the other bytes.

When we received the last of the 4 bytes, we write the value back to Serial, once as pure byte data and once as ASCII encoded string.

In Python you can use the code, you already used:

```py
arduino.write(struct.pack('>f',111.32))
```

You can read the output of the above sketch back with

```py
arduino.readline()
```

PS: From my tries I guess the previous problem with getting `ovf` was, that the byte order was reversed (which simply would have been solved by using `<f` for the struct in python). But I personally like this way better, because it uses less casting.

Comment: Thank you for this and previous answers !! This will do i guess.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way around dealing with serial bytewise, since the communication over serial relies on bytes as a unit. You can write the received bytes directly to the float variable. That is faster, than save them to a char array first:

```
float f = Serial.read() << 24;
f = ((unsigned long) f) | (Serial.read() << 16);
f = ((unsigned long) f) | (Serial.read() << 8);
f = ((unsigned long) f) | Serial.read();
```

With this the bytes of the float value have to be send with the order from most significant to least significant. I don't know, how the data is formatted, if you send a struct over python. The casting to `unsigned long` is important here to do the bitwise OR (`unsigned long` and `float` have both 4 bytes). (I tried it and it works for me)

Also be aware, that you shouldn't read from Serial, when there is no received byte in the buffer. You can check this with `Serial.available()`. If there is no new byte in the buffer the `Serial.read()` function returns an integer with value `-1`

EDIT:
The code above works, if you transmit the data directly as byte. In your comment you wrote, that you want to write `arduino.write(b"111.32")` in python. Here you are transmitting an ASCII string representation of the float number `111.32`. This is not as fast as transmitting byte data (since you may need way more bytes for one float than 4). In this case you can use either `Serial.parseFloat()` to get the float from the serial buffer (but ensure, that all bytes for this number have been received with `Serial.available()`) or you can save the bytes to a string and using `String.toFloat()` to get the float out of it.

Since you wanted to do it the fast way, you should transmit the numbers as byte data. To do this in python, have a look at the answer of [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3753/how-to-send-numbers-to-arduino-uno-via-python-3-and-the-module-serial). It explains the python code for it (be sure, that you get the ordering of the bytes the same in python and Arduino).

Comment: When I try your code it gives an error like `invalid operands of types 'float' and 'int' to binary 'operator|` to all |= operators. I can send the float number as `arduino.write(b"111.32")` . Will this be better for your approach? I also added the Serial.available() part thank you.

Comment: Ah, ok. Now I understand, what you are trying to do. I will edit my answer. And yes, I didn't anticipated, that you have to cast

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I am still stuck at a point. You say that i have to send it as byte data and the way I change a float number to a byte representation is `data = bytes(23.2)` right ? and then i try `arduino.write(data)` but `data = bytes(23.2)` gives an error which says  float object is not iterable. I know I ask much but can you also provide a python sample code please ? Or when i try to do it with `arduino.write(struct.pack('>f', 23.2))` it gives the serial output as `ovf`

Comment: I added a link to a question, which answers this for you

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have already checked that question and got the struct way from there. However, when I use your code to read the data i got overflow. Couldn't solve it. :( Updated the question accordingly